# Create TYPO3 Fluid link for typolink fields generated by a link wizard

Tags: hyperlink, typo3, fluid

I regularly use the link wizard in my TCA.

Its horrible to find out with conditions which kind of link I have to render in Fluid (page/email/external). Is there a solution for this or do I have to create my own ViewHelper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be undocumented, but you can pass it to `<f:link.page>` and it will be rendered correctly, even if it is external, email, or file link. This is because internally, `<f:link.page>` uses [UriBuilder](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_mvc_1_1_web_1_1_routing_1_1_uri_builder.html) to build the URL, and that UriBuilder uses Typolink.

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{myLinkFieldValue}">My link</f:link.page>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the ViewHelper i´m using for this (+a helper Class):
https://gist.github.com/BenjaminBeck/7220623

Answer (score 0):

I think the **link.typolink** ViewHelper is what you are looking for, at least for TYPO3 7.0 and above.

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{link}">
   Linktext
</f:link.typolink>
```

- See [Changelog Feature #59396 - TypolinkViewHelper](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/7.0/Feature-59396-TypolinkViewHelper.html) (TYPO3 7.0)
- see [link.typolink in ViewHelper Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/master/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/Typolink.html)

Answer (score -1):

```html
External Link -- 
<f:link.external uri="http://www.typo3.org" target="_blank">external link</f:link.external> 

Email -- 
<f:link.email additionalAttributes="{foo: 'bar'}" email="NULL" class="NULL" dir="NULL" id="NULL" lang="NULL" style="NULL" title="NULL" accesskey="NULL" tabindex="123" onclick="NULL" name="NULL" rel="NULL" rev="NULL" target="NULL">
 <!-- tag content - may be ignored! -->
</f:link.email>

Internal Link -- 
<f:link.page pageUid="1" additionalParams="{extension_key: {foo: 'bar'}}">page link</f:link.page>
```

Answer (score -2):

In Fluid, there are different link view helpers:

```
<f:link.action action="show">action link</f:link.action>
<f:link.email email="foo@bar.tld" />
<f:link.external uri="http://www.typo3.org" target="_blank">external link</f:link.external>
<f:link.page>page link</f:link.page>
```

The Code (and some examples) can be found at: typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Link